# CSS positioning so that middle layer always resizes to fill up the white space available on the page vertically such that there are no scrollbars?

Tags: html, css

I thought this should be quite simple but I am struggling and would appreciate any help.

I have an HTML page which is divided into 3 sections vertically. The top section and bottom sections are fixed heights (100px say) and the middle section contains a large image (say > 800 x 800px dimensions).

Something like this:

```
+--------------------------+
| Section 1 - 100px height |
+--------------------------+
|                          |
|                          |
|   Section 2 - Image      |
|                          |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
| Section 3 - 100px height |
+--------------------------+
```

The 2nd section + image should expand with the browser window so that there are no scroll bars.

I have tried a bunch of things including using the

```
height: calc(100% - 200px)
```

But this also did not work for me.
JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jygpqfaa/3/

What would be the right approach to tackle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Flexbox**, so if you set `flex: 1` on `middle` div it will take rest of window height.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.middle {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="middle">Your Content</div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nenad Vracar for the quick response! This looks great - however, when the content (in this case, my image) is large, it stretches the middle box and ends up having scroll bars. I have tried a bunch of things but the height seems to push the flex box boundaries. Any ideas? JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/saurabhj/gxwc621q/

Comment: You could use `calc` on image like this https://jsfiddle.net/gxwc621q/2/ or you could set image as background https://jsfiddle.net/gxwc621q/3/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using percentages, try using `vh`.

```
height: calc(100vh - 220px);
```

(extra `20px` for spacing)

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jygpqfaa/8/)

Comment: Thank you for this. It was quite dumb of me to miss this :)